# Assigning method return back to the variable which is the argument of the method in Vue3

Tags: vuejs3

Please, anybody explain why this does not work.
I am transferring "number" variable to the increase function as an argument. Function must increase it and return the number which I assign back to "number" variable.

```
<template>
    <h1>{{number}}</h1>
    <button @:click="number=increase(number)">Increase</button>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {  
               number: 0,
            };
        },
        methods: {
          increase(num){
            return num++
          }
        },
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saying what specifcally isn't working, but i assume that you are confused why the number ins't changing. Please read this part of the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment

You are returning the original value in your function and only after that the local number is incremented. Change it to the prefix operator:

```
increase(num) {
    return ++num
}
```